# How to I download yml environment file and activate with conda

Tags: python, virtual-environment

I'm very new to coding and trying to get everything to work with the given instructions. I installed miniconda3 and cloned and downloaded an environment provided by the instructor, but when I navigate to the directory and try to use "conda activate [name of environment]" it returns

EnvironmentNameNotFound: Could not find conda environment name_of_environment

I have my .yml file saved in the directory that is named correctly, and I have no idea where I'm messing up.

Additionally, when I use conda info --envs
it returns
base                  *  /Users/jonathanburton/miniconda3

and doesn't show the earth-analytics environment I have stored in my directory

I navigated to my directory (earth-analytics)
I used terminal to conda activate earth-analytics-python-env (which is the name of the environment)

I was expecting to activate the environment, however only
EnvironmentNameNotFound: Could not find conda environment earth_analytics_python_env

*EDIT* I did use

> conda env create -f environment.yml
> while in the target directory, and I can see the created YML file in that directory.

Comment: Hi! Did you install the environment with "conda env create -f environment.yml"?  as explained [here](https://github.com/earthlab/earth-analytics-python-env)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Solutions (2)**:

1. You can register the existing environment folder with conda so it will recognize it.

```
conda config --append --env earth_analytics_python_env {folder_path}
```

2. You can activate the environment directly by using its path.

```
conda activate {folder_path}
```

Comment: Hi Jesse, I tried this and put in >> conda config --append earth-analytics-python ~/Users/jonathanburton/earth-analytics/earth-analytics-python-env and it returned CondaValueError: Key 'earth-analytics-python' is not a known sequence parameter. is there any syntax I'm missing for this command?

Comment: Updated my solution. You need to specify --env to tell conda to append it to the config file. [Source](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/config.html)